# Verilog error: XXX is not a constant

Tags: verilog

I am doing my homework about making an ALU, and I get an error. I search it but didn't get the reason.Why does it happen?
The error message is S2 is not a constant.`case ({S2,S1,S0})`

```

````
module ALU(
    input S0,
    input S1,
    input S2,
    input IN1,
    input IN2,
    input IN3,
    output OUT1,
    output OUT2
    );


case ({S2,S1,S0})//{S2,S1,S0}
3'b000:
begin
    assign OUT1=IN1&IN2;//and a1(OUT1,IN1,IN2);
    assign OUT2 = 1'b0;
end
3'b001:
begin
    assign OUT1=IN1|IN2;//or o1(OUT1,IN1,IN2);
    assign OUT2=1'b0;
end
3'b010:
begin
    assign OUT1=!IN1;
    assign OUT2=1'b0;
end
3'b011:
begin
    assign OUT1=!IN2;
    assign OUT2=1'b0;
end
3'b100:
begin
    assign OUT1=IN1^IN2;
    assign OUT2=1'b0;
end
3'b101:FullAdder1 fa(.IN1(IN1),.IN2(IN2),.IN3(IN3),.OUT1(OUT1),.OUT2(OUT2));
3'b110:FullSubtracter1 fs(.IN1(IN1),.IN2(IN2),.IN3(IN3),.OUT1(OUT1),.OUT2(OUT2));
3'b111:
begin
    assign OUT1=1'b0;
    assign OUT2=1'b0;
end
default:
begin
    assign OUT1=1'b0;
    assign OUT2=1'b0;
end
endcase
endmodule

```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use assign and module declaration in your switch-case statement. The compiler take it as a generation statement, i.e. when elaborating the design, depending the select value, the generated design will be different.

However you can use generate statement only with constant (parameter for example) selection as you cannot re-generate hardware on the fly.

You have two things to do:

- Pass your outputs as regs(then do not use `assign` in the case but non-blocking assignment `<=`)
- instantiate your adder and substractor outside the case statement with  separate results wire which will be taken as value by your outputs in the corresponding cases.

Doing so will result in your outputs connected on the output of multiplexers controlled by `{S2,S1,S0}` and with the different inputs as you specified them in the switch-case statement.